# Calculate mean from a column based on another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have got a large csv file where the sample looks like the following (2 columns and many rows)

```
date    score
1/1/16  0
2/1/16  0
3/1/16  0.2732
3/1/16  -0.6486
4/1/16  0
5/1/16  0.4404
5/1/16  -0.2732
6/1/16  -0.5859
6/1/16  0.34
```

You can see that there are multiple same dates with different score in the sample (same as the original file where there are hundreds of same dates with scores). I want to average the score by date and then save it as a csv format. The expected result should look like this (for each date one average score)

```
date    Avg_Score
1/1/16  0
2/1/16  0
3/1/16  -0.1877
4/1/16  0
5/1/16  0.0836
6/1/16  -0.12295
```

How can I do it in Pandas module in Python? I checked stackoverflow for suggesstions and loc, iloc and groupby were all I found. But I could not make them useful I guess as this is what I have tried and still gets the same file as my original (nothing changes). Don't know why it is not working and how to get it to work.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')

df.groupby('date').mean().reset_index()

df.to_csv('average.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Would appreicate any help as I have been struggling with this for a while. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign output back of `groupby` method to variable, e.g. here `df1`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')
#solution with renamed new column
df1 = df.groupby('date')['score'].mean().reset_index(name='Avg_Score')
#your solution
#df1 = df.groupby('date').mean().reset_index()
df1.to_csv('average.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```